# Higher error with smaller batch size in pyTorch

Tags: pytorch, gradient-descent

In stochastic gradient descent, in a single epoch, smaller batch sizes should give smaller errors since smaller batch size means more updates to the variables. However, in one of my recent experiments using pyTorch when I decrease the batch size (from 512 to 32) the loss after the first epoch increased. Is this possible? What does it say about the training process? Is gradient descent diverging? Or anything else?

Comment: Smaller batch sizes generally mean larger gradients since the gradient is the average across all samples in the batch. That's why typically reduce the learning rate if you reduce the batch size, and vice versa. So your updates might be to large to properly learn. However, there could be many more other reasons.